# What does it mean when a series expansion has increasing negative order in epsilon as epsilon approaches 0?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

I'm trying to get an order bound on the following integral as $\epsilon \to 0$:

$$g(\epsilon) = \int_a^{a+\epsilon} f(\epsilon,v) dv$$ where $f$ is an ugly, but smooth, function when $a\leq |v| <a+\epsilon$. My issue is that when I attempt to expand $$g(\epsilon) = \epsilon f(0,a) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\big(2 f_\epsilon(0,a) + f_v(0,a)\big) + o(\epsilon^2),$$

I run into issues.  Namely, some terms go to infinity when evaluated at $\epsilon = 0$.  I also notice that, if I look (formally) at the same expansion without evaluating anything in $\epsilon$, the series order decreases with $\epsilon$ as I add more derivatives:  first $\epsilon^{-2}$, then $\epsilon^{-4}$, and so on.

Would someone please explain to me what is going on here? I have never done series calculations like this before, so a reference containing theory and/or examples would also be helpful.  Thanks,

Comment: Did you get that $$g'(\epsilon) = \int_a^{a+\epsilon} f_\epsilon (\epsilon,v)\, dv + f(\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did.  I then continued:

$$g''(\epsilon) = 2 f_\epsilon(\epsilon,a+\epsilon) + f_v(\epsilon, a+\epsilon) + \int_a^{a+\epsilon} f_{\epsilon\epsilon}(\epsilon,v)dv,$$

and tried to "plug in" $\epsilon = 0$.

I think my expansion is formally correct, but then again I am just using what I know about Taylor series and not thinking very hard about it.

Comment: So your problem is that $f_\epsilon(0, a)$ or $f_v(0,a)$ is infinite?

Comment: Exactly.  And some higher-order derivatives are "even more infinite" in the sense that they have higher negative order in epsilon.  So I'm not sure how to extract a useful order bound.

Comment: Taylor polynomials only exist at places where where the function is differentiable to the degree of the polynomial. If you are getting derivatives that are infinite at $\epsilon = 0$, that means the derivatives do not exist there, so this function cannot be estimated about $\epsilon = 0$ with a Taylor polynomial. You can try a Laurent expression instead, which may or may not work, depending on the nature of $f$.

Comment: To find a Laurent expression about $\epsilon = 0$, multiply $g$ by a sufficiently high power of $\epsilon$ that all of the derivatives to the level you are interested in are finite. Find the Taylor polynomial for this $\epsilon^kg(\epsilon)$, then divide it by $\epsilon^k$ to get an expression for $g(\epsilon)$. This expression will tend to be close for midrange $\epsilon$ values, but diverge from $g$ for both large and small $\epsilon$ values. (The infinite series version converges on an annulus about $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I am aware of Laurent series, but I do not think they will be useful to me here.  Since I need an order bound in terms of epsilon, it would not help to expand in something that will most probably contain arbitrarily negative powers of epsilon.

Comment: Without knowing more about $f$ and where you are getting these results, there isn't much we can help you with.